# How many combinations are there for the interior angles of a triangle?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Suppose the interior angles of a triangle are all Natural numbers. How many combinations of angles are there without repeating similar triangles? So for instance, {1,1,178}, {1,2,177},...But without relisting similar triangles {178,1,1}, {177,1,2},...

Comment: I just came up with the problem for fun. I am currently trying to find a solution. Will post if I get somewhere.

Comment: An idea to maybe play with: how many solutions are there to $x+y+z=180$ where $0<x,y,z<179$?  I know that there are many similar problems to this that can be found. A common way to tackle this is with generating functions.

Answer (score 2):

(I'm copying and updating an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1823010/number-of-positive-unordered-integral-solutions/1823391#1823391) I gave two days ago.)

Your "combinations of angles" are called *partitions of $180$ into three parts*, or $3$-partitions in the sequel.

Since $a$, $b$, $c$ have to be $\geq1$, by "stars and bars" there are ${(180-3)+2\choose 2}=15\,931$ ordered admissible triples summing to $180$. Here  each partition of $180$ with three different parts occurs six times, the $88$ $3$-partitions with exactly two equal parts occur  three times, and the partition $(60,60,60)$ occurs one time. If we now form the number
$$15\,931+ 3\cdot 88+5\cdot 1=16\,200$$
then all $3$-partitions of $180$ have been counted exactly six times. It follows that the number of $3$-partitions of $180$  is ${16\,200\over6}=2700$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1: Once you give the first two angles, third angle is given too.

Hint 2: To avoid repeating triangles, list the angles in increasing order.

Hint 3: If $\alpha\le\beta\le\gamma$ are the angles, then $\alpha\le60°$ and $\beta\le90°-\alpha/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are working with degrees, the question is that of finding triples $(a,b,c)$ with $a+b+c=180$, where $a,b,c$ are the interior angles. To avoid similar triangles, we may require that $180 \geq a\geq b\geq c \geq 0$ (resp. $178$, $1$ if you wish to avoid degenerate cases) . Suppose then we know $a$. $b,c$ sum to $b+c=180-a$ But since $b \geq c$, there are only $\lfloor \frac{180-a}{2}\rfloor$ possibilities for $(b,c)$, so the answer to the question is $\sum_{a=60}^{180} \lfloor \frac{180-a}{2}\rfloor$ (resp. $178$ for the upper bound)